# Can't detect scroll event on content editable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have tried almost every way to attach the scroll event to the content editable. No matter what, my handleScrollToUpdateRect does not trigger. I have tried the wheel event, which works but is not as responsive as the scroll event for my purpose to continuously update a rect as the content editable div is scrolled.

textField was defined previously with:

```
textField = document.activeElement;
```

```
$(textField).on('scroll click keyup', handleScrollToUpdateRect);
$('[contenteditable]').on('scroll keyup click', handleScrollToUpdateRect);
      
$(textField).on('mousemove scroll keyup click', handleScrollToUpdateRect);
      
textField.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
        setTimeout(() => {
          handleScrollToUpdateRect();
        }, 0);
      });
      
textField.addEventListener('scroll', handleScrollToUpdateRect, true);
Array.from(textField.children).forEach(function (child) {
        child.addEventListener('scroll', handleScrollToUpdateRect);
      });
      
textField.onscroll = function (e) {
        //console.log('scrolling');
        handleScrollToUpdateRect(e);
      };
```

Function to be triggered and console log does noting when scrolling inside and content editable div

```
  function handleScrollToUpdateRect(e) {

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      updateRect('rect-before-prompt');
      updateRect('rect-after-prompt');
      checkRectWithinTextField('rect-before-prompt');
      checkRectWithinTextField('rect-after-prompt');
    });
    console.log(' scrolling update rect');
  }
```

HTML

```
<div contenteditable="true" aria-multiline="true" role="textbox" class="notranslate IZ65Hb-YPqjbf fmcmS-x3Eknd h1U9Be-YPqjbf" tabindex="0" spellcheck="true" dir="ltr">"..."</div>
```

Comment: did you confirm that `document.activeElement` is actually the `div` when the code runs?  Do you get any `console.log`s from any of the events?

Comment: I did confirm that, for all of my other listeners it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround I have tried to make the wheel event simulate the scroll event. It works for my purpose.

I add a listener for the real wheel event, then I create another listener which triggers an interval that continuously fires the wheel event rapidly (every 10ms). Then I set a time out of 500ms so it doesn't run forever.

```js
let intervalId = null;
      let timeoutId = null;

      textField.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
        if (!e.isProgrammatic) {
          // Clear any existing interval and timeout
          if (intervalId) clearInterval(intervalId);
          if (timeoutId) clearTimeout(timeoutId);

          let counter = 0;
          intervalId = setInterval(function () {
            if (counter < 50) {
              // total of 100 events
              var wheelEvent = new WheelEvent('wheel', {
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true,
                view: window,
                deltaX: 0,
                deltaY: 0,
                deltaZ: 0,
              });

              wheelEvent.isProgrammatic = true;
              textField.dispatchEvent(wheelEvent);
              counter++;
            } else {
              clearInterval(intervalId); // Stop after 100 events
            }
          }, 10); // fires every 10ms

          // Set a timeout to stop the interval 1 second after the last real wheel event
          timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
          }, 500);
        }
      });

      // This will handle the programmatic wheel event
      textField.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
        if (e.isProgrammatic) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            handleScrollToUpdateRect();
          }, 0);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because `<input type="text">` is not scrollable.

Try using a `textarea` while making sure that the textarea is scrollable.

### HTML

```
<textarea type='text'>


</textarea>
```

### Javascript

```
textArea = document.activeElement;

textArea.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, true);

function handleScroll() {
    console.log('scroll');
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zedhappened/ns0mLaft/21/)

Comment: sorry, but i'm talking about content editable